# Javascript: Apple Pay Demo code valid JS?

Tags: javascript

I am looking at Apple Pay on the web startup code.

below, they have template code.  I am wondering how that is valid JS within the promise?  Where are the brackets after `if (canMakePayments)` ?  When I try to add brackets, my editor shows an error.

```
if (window.ApplePaySession) {
   var merchantIdentifier = 'example.com.store';
   var promise = ApplePaySession.canMakePaymentsWithActiveCard(merchantIdentifier);
   promise.then(function (canMakePayments) {
      if (canMakePayments)
         // Display Apple Pay button here.
}); }
```

Comment: brackets `{}` are optional if there is a single statement for the `if` ... `if(condition) single statement;` is the same as `if (condition) { single statement;}` - when in doubt, read the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else#Syntax)